# reload python module in running program "from outside"

Tags: python, module, runtime, reload, python-2.6

I have done a few hours worth of work in my program in python (which still runs now), but now I've found a bug in one of the modules which prevents me from saving. It would be a lot of work to replicate what I did, so I was wondering - is there a way to reload python module in a running program "from outside"?

To make my question clearer - imagine I have 2 python files:

```
# foo.py
def save(x):
    # there's a bug, pirnt instead of print
    pirnt 'saved: ', x
```

and

```
# main.py
import foo

# a lot of work here
precious_data = 'abc'
while True:
    s = raw_input()
    try:
        foo.save(precious_data)
    except Exception as e:
        print 'error:', e
```

And I've just discovered I have bug in `foo.py`, it printed an error, but `main.py` handled it and is still running with those precious data.

**Is there any way I could force the python interpreter to reload `foo.py` while `main.py` is still running?**

The example is simplyfied, but real application has the same logic - i.e. there is only one call to `foo.py` from `main.py` on some cue (button clicked in reality), there is no data, objects or classes from `foo.py` persistently stored in `main.py`, so I was hoping it may be (at least theoreticaly) possible..

Additional information:

- debian 6, linux 3.2, 64bit
- python2.6
- `main.py` was executed from commandline (bash)
  *

Comment: It seems to be possible using gdb: https://stripe.com/blog/exploring-python-using-gdb ..